# jQuery show method not working

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I dont why this simple thing doesnt work.

please help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/VYqdt/

```
function showDivs(activediv) {
    $("#tabs > div").hide();
    $(activediv).show();
}

//while activediv is a 
    showDivs($(this).attr("href"));
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("href")` is a string. How do you want to show it ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `showDivs(this)` rather than `showDivs($(this).attr("href"))`?

Comment: Why do you need a separate function at all, what's wrong the usual way -> `$(this).show().siblings('div').hide();`?

Comment: how do i delete this question :P

Comment: @STEEL As there was a correct answer before you asked for deletion, I won't vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you div id is

```
<div id="#2013-04-20">#2013-01-02 content</div>
```

and selector becomes

```
$('#2013-04-20').show(); //which is selecting a div with "id='2013-04-20'"
```

and since you have `#` infront of id.. the selector won't be able to find that element

so try this

```
 <div id="2013-04-20">#2013-01-02 content</div> //remove the # in id
  <div id="2013-03-20">#2013-03-20 content</div> //remove the #
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/VYqdt/22/)

**and yes it is best to avoid id starting with numbers ....**

Comment: hahaha omg. im so silly. I copy pasted hrefs there :P

Comment: happens sometime.. :) :)

Comment: im so sorry all, for a SILLY question. im really sorry. i dont know how i missed that.

Comment: no worries.. happens sometime.. .. i think its time for you to go for a coffee now.. :) :) :p

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues.

**First**, ID's should not start with a number. [From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

**Second**, you should remove the `#` from the href and apply is in the method when it's needed.

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYqdt/23/) (I appended an `a` to your ID's so they didn't start with a number).